# Facebook feed image optimum dimensions

Tags: facebook

I've struggled for a long time to find the right dimensions for Facebook feed images, such that:

a) it fills the width of the feed column
b) image corruption is minimised (jpeg?)
c) maximum height is used without reducing width

Obviously it looks really poor when you're posting quality marketing images.  Does anyone know what algorithm they use to determine when the image becomes resized?

Comment: If StackOverflow is the wrong place for this, please advise where I should move the question to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images

Follow those instructions and you will be fine. Everything else may be resized to thumbnail size.